# Observable with async pipe is undefined/null in element when accessing property where select query is ran from parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, parent-child, ngrx

This always ends up being undefined when the select is ran in the parent component.

```
//parent component
export class baseCardComponent implments OnInit {
    scorecardHeader$: Observable<ScorecardHeader>;

    constructor(protected store: Store<State>){}
    ngOnIt() {
       this.scorecardHeader$ = this.store.select(getScorecardHeader);
    }
}

//child component HTML
<scorecard-header [header]="scorecardHeader$ | async"></scorecard-header>

//scorecardHeader component HTML
<div>Name: {{header.Name}}</div> <---scorecardHeader will always be undefined in this instance--WHY??
```

this works however...WHY?? Since it an observable being passed in async, wouldn't it wait for it to complete regardless of whether it is in the child or parent component?

```
//parent component
export class baseCardComponent implments OnInit {
    scorecardHeader$: Observable<ScorecardHeader>;

    constructor(protected store: Store<State>){}
    ngOnIt() {

    }
}

//child component HTML
<scorecard-header [header]="scorecardHeader$ | async"></scorecard-header>

//child component
export class myCard extends baseCardComponent implments OnInit{
  constructor(store: Store<State>){super(store);}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.scorecardHeader$ = this.store.select(getScorecardHeader);
  }
}
//scorecardHeader component HTML
<div>Name: {{header.Name}}</div> <---scorecardHeader now works...WHY??
```

Any help as to how to ensure the ScorecardHeader Observable works properly when it is set in the parent? I don't want to have to do this in every child component as this will lead to a LOT of redundant code as there are over 35 child components. Changing the store modifier to public DOES NOT fix this issue.

Comment: Your first solution should work fine, but there is not enough info to determine why it doesn’t..

Comment: Can you provide html and ts code of both parent and child components from the first approach?

Comment: @GytisTG there is no code in the child component ts file, only the HTML. There is really nothing else that needs to be shown, I have shown the select query in the parent and the HTML from the child. Parent is not a selector, only a parent component

Comment: But you do have `<scorecard-header>` tag, so there should be something as this is a custom html tag. Perhaps you can share a link to live server with example code? :)

Comment: yes scorecard header is the component being used in child component(and many others---it is neither a parent or a child, just a separate component). The baseCardComponent doesn't have a selector, that is the parent component.

Comment: Maybe a question mark will help in here: `<div>Name: {{header?.Name}}</div>`. As as Observable is undefined first then its value is updated and it will be displayed correctly

Comment: @igor_c I tried this...it stops the errors from occurring but it doesn't show up. I even have subscribed to the select query in the parent component and then set it to another property once it returns to ensure there is data there that then gets passed into the input and the value is still null...I don't get it at all

Comment: So this gets even stranger.  In the child component, I implement OnChanges to see what the values are when the parent subscription values get set and it doesn't even go into it at all.  But the OnChanges in the other components where the values are being passed gets hit even though it keeps showing up as null.  So somehow it appears the child component does not see the values being set at all, even though they are.  This is extremely strange behavior and I don't understand it at all...

Comment: Fixd. The issue? Not using super.ngOnInit() in the child...

Answer (score 0):

So this issue has been solved...basically the only thing I needed to do was call
`super.ngOnInit()` in the child component, and it worked without any changes.